# Bound mismatch warning in java generics

Tags: java, generics

Please have a look at below code listing :-

```
package com.test;

class XParam implements Comparable<XParam>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(XParam o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Comparable<XParam> param = new XParam() ;

        SomeClass object = new SomeClass() ;
        object.setData( param );

    }
}
```

Now,

> object.setData( param ); //third statementt in the main method in above code listing

compiles fine, if i make SomeClass generic with formal type parameter

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

as shown below :-

```
class SomeClass<T extends Comparable<T>>{

    public void setData(T data) {
    }
}
```

But, **object.setData( param );** gives below compile time error in eclipse :-

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method setData(T) of type SomeClass is not applicable for the 
 arguments (Comparable<XParam>). The inferred type Comparable<XParam> is not a valid 
 substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>>
```

if i apply the same formal type parameter at method level, rather then adding it at class level as shown below :-

```
class SomeClass{

    public <T extends Comparable<T>>void setData(T data) {
    }
}
```

Any good explanation/reference to understand this concept is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think something is not right with your description. `SomeClass object = new SomeClass();` is the raw (non generic) version of `SomeClass`. I don't understand how you are getting the bound mismatch there.

Comment: @BheshGurung : It's on the line object.setData( param );

Answer (score 1):

I think the only reason you're getting a bound mismatch with one way and not the other is because it doesn't seem you are parametrizing the declaration of `SomeClass`, and are thus using a raw type. If you use a raw type, the compiler doesn't bother with any generic checks, so you get no complaints.

I think that if you attempted to genericize your class with `Comparable<XParam>` you would get the same error you got when you tried to call the generic method with an incorrect bound.

---

As for the generic method, the error makes sense.

If your bound is `T extends Comparable<T>`, and you pass the method a `Comparable<XParam>`, the compiler will infer `T == Comparable<XParam>` and the method will look to see if the argument extends `Comparable<T> == Comparable<Comparable<XParam>>`. Which it doesn't.

I *believe* that your method will work if you call the method with an argument of type `XParam`, as `XParam extends Comparable<XParam>`.